# Odoo: how to know who installed a specific module?

Tags: module, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

My question is about who installed a specific module in a environment production, because a few days ago I found a module that was not among the purchased modules

Answer (score 1):

Odoo logs module install on `info` log level so if your log level is set `info` and you have the log files, you can just use `grep` tool to find log lines of installing that module.

```
grep -P 'ALLOW access to module.(button_immediate_install|button_install) on \[.*\]' log_file
```

This will match all the module install/upgrade line in the log file. If you want to limit for a specific module installation, you can replace `\[.*\]` with `\[.*module_name.*\]` pattern.

```
2018-08-28 10:20:42,825 26271 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.module.module: ALLOW access to module.button_immediate_install on ['module_name'] to user admin #1 via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

So you get the corresponding user and IP address for the particular module installation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try your solution